# Geoserver - empty native SRS field

Tags: postgis, geoserver, shapefile, coordinate-system

I'm converting layers from shape files to postgis with the below command:

```
shp2pgsql -s 22175 -c  -W "latin1" path/file.dbf' table_name db_name | psql -d db_name
```

Next, I add this layer to the GeoServer but the field `native SRS` is empty.
I thought that the SRID were wrong so I run:

```
SELECT ST_SRID(geom) FROM table_name;
```

And to my surprise I get 22175 the conversion is not the problem. What I am doing wrong?

Note: already exits other layers have been added (by someone else) and that layers have the field `native SRS` filled with value `EPSG:22175`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you check the geometry_columns table?

Comment: The table is empty. But if this is the problem, why the others layers works?

Answer (score 5):

In my experience the native SRS field is empty usually because the user, as which Geoserver is accessing the database, does not have at least SELECT rights to the table.

Comment: Either the table, or the metadata views/tables.

Comment: That, **and** you have to start from a new store if the table owner was wrong in PostGIS (that is, if you had to update it with `ALTER TABLE … OWNER TO …`).

Comment: Is starting from a new source the only way? I have a flow where I copy computation results from an outside database into the Geoserver PostGIS database. The source is in other words updated. The new layer is indeed missing the source sis...

Comment: You can create an SQL view instead, just using a standard "SELECT * FROM table_name", and that seems to "refresh" it