# Inserting new data in PostGIS are not displayed automatically in Geoserver layer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers-2, cache

I have build an application using PostGIS, geoserver and openlayers2.12 and I am facing the following problem:
When I add some data in my Postgis tables, geoserver doesn't get refreshed properly and the new data (lines and points) are not shown on the map.
If I zoom in the map I get some parts of my new data (parts of lines and all the points). But when I zoom out I can not see anything.
Also when I do "Layer Preview" I don't see the new geometries.

I tried to delete the cache of the layer and my browser..but no luck.
What solves the problem is if I delete and then recreate the layer.
Then everything its shown. But doing this I loose all my cache and the application becomes slow.

Any idea what It can cause this behavior?

Comment: Are the new features which you add still within the original extents of the layer? Do you get the added features with WFS GetFeature request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

concerning your question about how to update the bounding-boxes:

**Choose the layers menu:**

[image]

--

**Click on the layer in the layers list:**

[image]

--

**Recalculate the bounds**

[image]

If the extent keeps changing you could perhaps try to set the extent manually to the world extent...

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer comes bundled with GeoWebCache.

Have a go at truncating that cache.

Go to your GeoServer Admin Console in the web browser and choose the 'Tile Layers' section, then go to 'seed/truncate'. You can also do this directly with GWC by going to http://yourserver:8080/geoserver/gwc.

See below:

[image: GeoServer Tile Layers]

[image: truncate GWC]

Comment: I tried that but I still don't see the newly added information. I read here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16996/geoserver-layer-from-postgis-not-updating that I might need to update the bounding box of the store but I don't know how to do this. Any idea?

Comment: For sure one think I have to do is to recompute the Bounding Boxes (compute from data) inside the Layer options.

Comment: Why exact bounding box is necessary for you? I would just make the initial BBOX so big that all data that will come in later for sure falls inside it. Only drawback I can imagine is too wide bounding box in WMS GetCapabilities.